# Changing the site root in plone.app.testing/Plone 4

Tags: plone, zope

Is there a way to change the `PLONE_SITE_ID` from its default at `plone.app.testing.interfaces` without modifying the source code?

I'm using Plone 4 with several custom products, and `plone.app.testing` (4.0.2) with relative success. In my custom products, there are several instances where there are hardcoded physical paths to locate objects when performing catalog searches (e.g., my site root is 'mySiteID', so several custom queries use `path=/mySiteID/folder1/etc..` to do catalog searches).

The problem is that the site root in the Plone instance that `plone.app.testing` configures (`PLONE_FIXTURE`) is `PLONE_SITE_ID = 'plone'`. Therefore, any objects that I add in my tests always have `/plone` as the root rather than `/mySiteID` and my tests break. I can fix this problem by changing the defined value in the interface but this seems like an ugly hack.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much better to not hardcode your paths in your queries? Obtain the path from a context object, for example.

Comment: I agree. However, I have to deal with a lot of legacy code and I don't anticipate changing the name of the site at any point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely *have* to, you could monkeypatch the id; do so as part of the test runner part, in buildout:

```
[test]
# ...
initialization =
    import plone.app.testing.interfaces
    plone.app.testing.interfaces = 'mySiteID'
```

Answer (score 1):

Martijn is correct. Though, his answer does not fully do the trick. You need to monkey patch multiple plone.app.testing imports to make this actually work:

```
[test] 
...

initialization =
    import plone.app.testing.helpers
    plone.app.testing.helpers.PLONE_SITE_ID = 'Plone'
    import plone.app.testing.interfaces
    plone.app.testing.interfaces.PLONE_SITE_ID = 'Plone'
    import plone.app.testing.layers
    plone.app.testing.layers.PLONE_SITE_ID = 'Plone'
```